# xTaskGetTickCount() always returns 0

Tags: c, freertos, stm32f4discovery

I working on STM32F4 Discovery with FreeRTOS ver 9. I use xTaskGetTickCount to see how long my task is working on. But xTaskGetTickCount always returns 0. This is my task code

```
    void test_print(void)
    {
      uint32_t wake_time,temp1,temp2;
      const uint32_t period = 100;
      char buff[32];

      wake_time = xTaskGetTickCount();
      while(1)
      {
         temp1 = xTaskGetTickCount();
         sprintf(buff,"Tick1 = %u\n",temp1);
         USART_puts(buff);

         USART_puts("aaaaaaaaaaa\n");
         //vTaskDelay(1000);
         delay_dw(500);

         temp2 = xTaskGetTickCount();
         sprintf(buff,"Tick2 = %u\n",temp2);

         USART_puts(buff);
         vTaskDelayUntil(&wake_time,period);
       }

     }
```

And this is my main function

```
int main (void)
{
    USART_Config();
    //configASSERT();
    USART_puts("TEST\n");   

    xTaskHandle handler = NULL;
    xTaskCreate(test_print,"Test_Print",512,NULL,TASK_PRINT_PRIO,(xTaskHandle *) NULL);

    vTaskStartScheduler();
    USART_puts("Scheduller ERROR"); 

    for(;;);
}
```

Anyone Help? Thank You.

Comment: Have you called `vTaskStartScheduler()` before `xTaskGetTickCount()`? Keep in mind that `xTaskGetTickCount()` returns the count of ticks since vTaskStartScheduler was called.

Comment: Where is the `main()` function?  Where is the statement: `#include task.h`  Please post code that cleanly compiles, is small, and still shows the problem.

Comment: of critical importance, here is the syntax for the function in question: `volatile TickType_t xTaskGetTickCountFromISR( void );`  Notice that it does NOT return a `uint32_t` but rather a `TickType_t`  Your compiler should have told you about that problem.

Comment: I'm already add the main function. Sorry before if I'm not include the main function @user3629249

Comment: The TickType_t that I used is the same with uint32_t because I already open in the portmacro.h in the FreeRTOS library API @user3629249